# How to change the last person to edit a file

Tags: c#, .net, file, edit

Is there a way to change the last person to edit a file? I can get the last user to edit it with this code...

```
string FileLocation = @"C:\test.txt";
FileInfo droppedFile = new FileInfo(FileLocation);
FileSecurity fileSecurity = droppedFile.GetAccessControl();
IdentityReference identityReference = fileSecurity.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount));
string userName = identityReference.Value;
Console.WriteLine(userName);
```

...but how do I change it?

Comment: _How_ are you trying to change it?

Comment: They are going to know it was you - you will have to deal with it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cant change usage data of a file with coding. That way security rules would be useless.

Comment: You could impersonate their identity, and then edit the file and save it, couldn't you? Of course, it would take the appropriate permissions to do that.

Comment: How so? The part about obtaining the appropriate permissions? That is true for any software you write.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that would require tricking the operating system and bypassing its security mechanisms, which I don't think is possible.